# Apex test class for Standard Controller extensions - Test problem

Tags: apex, failing-tests, controller-extension, apextestrunresult

:) I am writing test class for controller extensions, but I get the error: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Asset to Account.

Can you please look at my code, and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Controller Extensions:

```
    public class assetonaccount{

    public List<Asset> device{
        get;
        set;
    }
    
    public assetonaccount(
        ApexPages.StandardController controller
    ){  
       
        device = 
            [
                SELECT 
                    AssetLevel,
                    Id,
                    Name, SerialNumber, InstallDate, Last_Calibration__c, Next_Calibration__c, Asset_tag_no__c
                FROM   
                    Asset
                WHERE  AssetLevel = 1 AND
                    AccountId = 
                        :((Account)controller.getRecord()).Id
            ];
    }
}
```

Apex Test Class:

```
    @isTest
private class AssetOnAccountTest {
    
  static testMethod void TestAccountOnAssetExtensions()
  {
     date installdate = System.today() - 20;
     date nextcal = System.today() + 15;
     date lastcal = System.today() - 7;

      //Insert Account
      Account acct = new Account(Name='TestClassAccount', Customer_Segment__c = 'Hospitals', Calibration_Intervals__c = 'Half year');
      insert acct;

      // Retrieve the new Account
      acct = [SELECT Id,Name,Customer_Segment__c, Calibration_Intervals__c FROM Account WHERE Id =:acct.Id];

      //Insert Asset
      Asset asst = new Asset(Name='Asset test', SerialNumber = '1234', InstallDate=installdate, Last_Calibration__c=lastcal, Next_Calibration__c=nextcal, Asset_tag_no__c='12', AccountId=acct.id);
      insert asst;

     //Retrieve the new asset
      asst = [SELECT Id, AssetLevel, Name, SerialNumber, InstallDate, Last_Calibration__c, Next_Calibration__c, Asset_tag_no__c from Asset WHERE Id =:asst.Id];

      
      ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(asst);
      
      assetonaccount controller = new assetonaccount(stdController);
      
      system.assertNotEquals(controller.device, null);
      system.assertEquals(controller.device.size(), 1); 
      system.assertEquals(controller.device[0].Last_Calibration__c, lastcal);
      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're instantiating the `StandardController`, your passing an `Asset` record. In the `assetonaccount` class your constructor method calls `controller.getRecord()` which will return the record your passed in when creating the `StandardController` instance ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm#apex_ApexPages_StandardController_ctor)), which was an `Asset` record. You then attempt to [Cast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm) that record to an `Account` with the following code:

```
((Account)controller.getRecord()).Id
```

Which is not allowed, because and `Asset` is never a type of `Account`. It appears your intention is to retrieve all `Assets` for a particular `Account` in which case you should use the `AccountId` field from the `Asset` record. i.e.

```
// Get the account Id for the current asset
Id accountId = ((Asset)controller.getRecord()).AccountId;  

// Load all other assets for the account
device = [
  SELECT 
    AssetLevel,
    Id,
    ...
  FROM   
    Asset
  WHERE
    AssetLevel = 1
  AND
    AccountId = :accountId
];
```

Comment: Hi! :) I changed the code as you wrote, but now I am getting new error message: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Asset.AccountId

I added the accountId into query. The error message shows on line 11, below device query where I added the Id accountId = ((Asset)controller.getRecord()).AccountId;

Comment: It works! Thank you! I added the accountId into device query on test class :)